# Jenkins amazon-ecr plugin issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, plugins, jenkins, docker

I'm using `amazon-ecr` plugin for Jenkins, it went well for a long time and suddenly broke today

```
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
net.sf.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 0 of 
    at net.sf.json.util.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:499)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromJSONTokener(JSONObject.java:919)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromString(JSONObject.java:1145)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:162)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:132)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.credentials.DockerRegistryToken$1.call(DockerRegistryToken.java:91)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.credentials.DockerRegistryToken$1.call(DockerRegistryToken.java:71)
    at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:45)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.credentials.DockerRegistryToken.newKeyMaterialFactory(DockerRegistryToken.java:71)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.credentials.DockerRegistryEndpoint.newKeyMaterialFactory(DockerRegistryEndpoint.java:204)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.credentials.DockerRegistryEndpoint.newKeyMaterialFactory(DockerRegistryEndpoint.java:193)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder$Perform.executeCmd(DockerBuilder.java:404)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder$Perform.executeCmd(DockerBuilder.java:382)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder$Perform.buildAndTag(DockerBuilder.java:326)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder$Perform.exec(DockerBuilder.java:274)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder$Perform.access$100(DockerBuilder.java:254)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder.perform(DockerBuilder.java:225)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:782)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Build step 'Docker Build and Publish' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Docker Build runs fine, if I remove the ECR auth and fails only at push.

I have no knowledge in java, and not sure what, the above error says

**Update**
This feels to be a issue with Jenkins upgrade. Installing fresh Jenkins and amazon-ecr does work fine.

Leaving the question open.
thanks much,
Shan

Answer (score 0):

`/var/lib/jenkins/.dockercfg` might become blank for some reason.

Try removing that file and rerunning build job.

That should generate new .dockercfg file and the issue will be fixed.